# Is my understanding of this corollary correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The following is a theorem/corollary pair in an introductory abstract algebra course.

> **Theorem:** $f(x)\equiv g(x) $ mod $p(x)$ if and only if $[f(x)]=[g(x)]$, where $[h(x)]=h(x)$ mod $p(x)$.
>
> **Corollary:** Assume $p(x)\in F[x]$ has degree $n$. Let $S$ be the set of all polynomials with degree less than $n$ together
>   with the zero polynomial. Then every congruence class modulo $p(x)$ is
>   the class of some polynomial in $S$ and the congruence classes of
>   different polynomials in $S$ are distinct.

I just wanted to double check my understanding of the theorem and the corollary. I'm a little more confused about the corollary because I'm not quite sure what they mean by "is the class of some polynomial in $S$". Here is my understanding of both of them, in layman's terms.

> **Theorem:** Two polynomials are equivalent mod $p(x)$ iff their residues are the same mod $p(x)$.
>
> **Corollary:** The remainders under polynomial long division with $p(x)$, over the field $F$, are unique.

Comment: "Let $S$ be the set of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$ together with the zero polynomial." Shouldn't it just be degree less than $n$ (not equal)?

Comment: My apologies, indeed strictly less than $n$.

Comment: Yes, by the Polynomial Division Algorithm, said set of remainders forms a complete system of distinct reps for the congruence classes of $\,F[x]\ {\rm mod}\ p(x).\ \ $